# Django, guidelines for writing a clean method for a ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I have read the docs and I can only find guidelines on how to write a clean method for a field **within** a form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

However I have created a field which inherits from `ModelChoiceField`. I wish to add some custom validation and cleaning, attached to the field and **not** the form, because the field is used in multiple forms, hence keeping it DRY.

I can take a stab at creating a clean method, but eactly what args are passed in, and what should be returned seems to be lacking in the documentation, or I can't find it.

Here my field that I wish to add custom cleaning and validation to:

```py
class FooChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, required=True):
        queryset = Foo.objects.filter(enabled=True).order_by('name')
        super().__init__(
            widget=forms.RadioSelect,
            queryset=queryset,
            to_field_name='id',  # The radio button value field
            required=required,
            empty_label=None,
        )
        self.error_messages = {
            'required': "Please select a Foo.",
            'invalid_choice': "Invalid Foo selected, please try again.",
        }

    # Pass the whole DB object into the template so one can access all fields
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj
```

Heres a guess at it, although it is called, the cleaned field always ends up as `None`, even when its valid:

```py
class FooChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    ...

    def clean(self, value):
        if value != 'correct':
            raise ValidationError("Value is challenged in it's correctness")
        return value

    def validate(self, obj):
        if obj.foo != 'foo':
            raise ValidationError("Validation Error on foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a model field, and the validation is re-used, you should move the validation on the model itself

```
def validate_correct(value):
    if value != 'correct':
        raise ValidationError("!",  code='incorrect')


class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(
        max_length=31,
        validators=[validate_correct],
    )
```

If you want to keep your new form field, you should add some validators too

```
class MyModelChoiceFields(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    default_validators = [validate_correct]
    default_error_messages = {'incorrect': "This is not correct"}
```

Comment: The custom clean method should not run on the admin website, only on a few forms I have, hence in my case it is not applicable to place the clean/validation code on the model.